# Replacing a single dual shaft stepper motor with 2 stepper motors

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a stepper motor that is 42x42x60mm (width, length, height) and has a shaft in the front and back of the motor.  This thing has finally given out and won't rotate even when powered down.  But I cannot find a motor like this anywhere and this is on a $1000 3d printer.

So I am wondering could I replace this motor with 2 steppers back-to-back?  I have to keep the stepper driver the same so is there a way to tie two motors into the same driver, like just by connecting the lines of the two motors? One major problem I forsee is that 2 steppers back-to-back will oppose each other for cw and ccw rotations.

Comment: `won't rotate even when powered down` maybe the bearings could be replaced

Comment: Are you sure? Quick search found some options NEMA17 (ie 42mm x 42mm) and 60mm and dual shaft, in first page of Google results. Obv there are many motor specs to check, but I suspect the effort of getting a replacement part is less than reinventing. It's not that unusual a size.

Comment: Also if you run two steppers in parallel it would pull more current, all things being equal, possibly affecting driver performance if it's designed to squeeze out a lot of performance.

Comment: There are plenty of dual shaft stepper motors, the price is around 50 bucks for such.  Question is, what is mounted on the other end, or why do you need a dual shaft?

Comment: SF2424-10B11 see the price on Mouser. Extra you need a connecting cable /w connector 4835775-1 or DIY a connector with cable.

Answer (score 1):

Put a shaft between two bearings with a gear and drive the gear from a new motor.

Make sure that the output matches the travel needed so the gearing may need to increase or decrease the motor output.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, but I would much rather use 2 steppers if possible.  It wouldn't require me to make new brackets among other changes.  But if my question is not possible, this idea might save my printer